# Как работать с локальным файлом .sql в pymysql?

Tags: python, pymysql

Вместе со скриптом в папке проекта находиться .sql файл базы данных, могу ли я работать с этим файлом в моём проекте? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Модуль `pymysql` не предоставляет возможности выполнить SQL файл целиком.

`pymysql` позволяет выполнять отдельные SQL команды.

***НО*** разбить SQL файл на SQL команды - очень нетривиальная задача. Файл может содержать многострочные команды, комментарии, явные транзакции, процедуры, функции, тригеры и т.д. В общем вам придется повторить всю ту работу, которую проделали создатели `MySQL client` / `MySQL Shell`. Логичнее будет воспользоваться результатами их труда - [запустить `mysql client` из Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563950/5741205):

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['/path/to/mysql', db, '-u', user, '-p', passwd,  '<', '/path/to/script.sql']
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

PS бинарник `mysql` должен находится на той машине, с которой запускается Python скрипт